# Can't edit my app information

Tags: facebook

I'm not able to change information about my application. I'm opening application page (http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=appid) click **Edit info**, then **Edit App Information**. But I get to this page https://developers.facebook.com/apps/appid/advanced where I can't edit the mein app info.

When this problem is going to be fixed?

Comment: Its working fine and did you tried from the facebook application dashboard https://developers.facebook.com/apps ??

Comment: @Vijay It isn't working, I just can change the app description, which is meant to be shown in the news feed. I'm very sorry, but I can't edit information on the following page http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=appid&sk=info

http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/7516/1dc0420ea5a74409b161eef.png

Comment: Are you sure that you are assigned the admin role for this app? And for editing any application related info goto http://developers.facebook.com/apps and not in http://facebook.com/apps

Comment: Same problem here, just noticed today! Perhaps the link changed with rolling out the new facebook changes? Anyway, can't change what's displayed if someone clicks the Info link in the sidebar - frustrated!